# Usercontrol command parameter from parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, mvvm-light

In my wpf project I have a usercontrol containing the menu bar for my program. Im not sure thats the right way to do it, but nice way to keep i seperated. This menu bar contains of lot of buttons with command bindings using mvvmlight toolkit eventtocommand, this works perfectly. But I have a print button where I would need to pass a Visual object from mainwindow to the commandparameter in the usercontrol.

Usercontrol.xaml - where MasterGrid is the elementname in mainwindow.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Print" Command="{Binding PrintDiagramCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MasterGrid}" 
          InputGestureText="Ctrl+P">
   <MenuItem.Icon>
       <Image Height="24" Width="24" Source="/Resources/Icons/print.ico"/>
   </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , though I have'nt tested it . there is a difference in ElementName and x:Reference of how the element is been found as contextmenu is not the part of VisualTree so ElementName wont work.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference MasterGrid}}"
```

I hope this will help.

> > **Note:** Its not a good practice to access elements in ViewModel.

Comment: @ethcallogics thanks for the answer. Not quite sure how to do the way you mention, but would it then be better to do it in a different way? and what is that? Edit: I have to pass a Visual object such that I can print it. Im about to make a diagram designer.

Comment: As far as my understanding Print it from View Why to Pass it to ViewModel . Create a Task and Print it in this Task so that UI thread wont block.ViewModel is responsible for the behavior based upon data and Printing aint seeting any behavior.

Comment: I think that I might have been unclear. I have a MainWindow with a MainGrid and a menuBarUserControl. The button which activates the print command is placed in the usercontrol, the Visual (the grid) I want to print is the MainGrid in the MainWindow.